# ERD Diagram - Shopping Cart

Tags: erd

I am new to database design and having a trouble on the database design for shopping cart for an online shopping system.

The system will have 3 catagories, Book, Videos, Games.The shopping cart are able to store these items and check out.

For the ERD, my idea was:
1 Cart can have 1 or many Products
1 or many products are in 1 Catagory.

My question is,for example, the book has an ISBN attribute while Video does not,
thus I cannot put them into the single "Product" entity,
but if I seperate them into three..

1 Cart can have 0 or many Books.
1 Cart can have 0 or many Videos.
1 Cart can have 0 or many Games.

So there is a situation that there may have all "0" situation,
but it does not make senses as the cart must have at least one product inside.

Sorry for my pool english~Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly I can't see what's the problem with having 0 items in a shopping cart. When you go to a real shop and you collect a cart it initially has 0 items. So this makes perfect sense.

I am not sure what the proper notation/language is for an ERD, but in terms of software classes I think you should have.

Shopping cart - contains 0 or more `Product`s

Product

- Id ~ a field you auto-generate
- List item
- Name
- Description
- Price
- etc.

Which has subclasses

Book

- ISBN
- Author
- Publisher
- etc.
- List item

Video

- Length
- Actor
- Director
- etc.
- List item

Game

- Genre
- List item
- Platform
- etc.

Even if you keep the three different product types (book, video, game) as entirely separate it doesn't mean you cart can't contain 0 objects.

Comment: Thanks!But I am not sure if the concept inheritance can be implemented in database design?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048151/what-are-the-options-for-storing-hierarchical-data-in-a-relational-database